# What's the effect of "range" on :lua and :luafile commands?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

The `:lua` and `:luafile` commands take an optional `[range]` specification.  But it's unclear what effect it has (unlike the `:luado` command, where the effect is explained clearly in the help text).

Is there some way for the invoked chunk of Lua code to ask what the range was?

For example, the result of `vim.api.nvim_get_current_line()` is unaffected by the range.  And for the `nvim_buf_get_lines()` function you have to pass start and end line numbers explicitly (there's no magic passing through of the command's range to these functions, AFAICT).

Answer (score 1):

> it's unclear what effect it has

It is ignored.

> Is there some way for the invoked chunk of Lua code to ask what the range was?

As an example,

```
command! -range -nargs=1 MyLua
    \ call v:lua.loadstring('local line1, line2 = select(1, ...);'
    \   .. <q-args>)(<line1>, <line2>)

:/foo/,/bar/MyLua for n, l in pairs(vim.fn.getline(line1, line2)) do print(line1 - 1 + n, l) end
```